# Extrinsic vs intrinsic geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let’s say I have two geodesics on an embedded surface. If I was to find the separation vector of two geodesics, find the double derivative of that vector and then project it onto the surface, would I expect to get the same result as if I had done this analysis intrinsically?

Comment: What is the "separation vector" exactly?  Can you write an equation for it?

Comment: It is the vector which is being differentiated in the jacobi equation. I would just like to know, is it possible to derive the jacobi equation without resorting to intrinsic geometry? Can we do that analysis involving normal vectors and the like and then projecting down on the surface?

Comment: @JesseMadnick it’s the variation vector field for a parametrized family of curves (geodesics here), i.e if $\Gamma(s,\cdot)$ is a 1-parameter family of curves, then it is the vector field $V=\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial s}\bigg|_{s=0}$ along the curve $\gamma=\Gamma(0,\cdot)$. Anyway, this exact question was posted on PhySE [where I just answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/783585/203278).

Comment: The separation or Jacobi field, as @peek-a-boo says, is the first (not second) derivative with respect to the variational parameter, which does not depend on either the metric or connection. It therefore is the same when done intrinsically or extrinsically. The Jacobi equation is obtained by differentiating the Jacobi field twice with respect to the arc length parameter. Both derivatives use the intrinsic connection and therefore if you use the extrinsic connection then you have to project into the tangent space twice.